# How to achieve a unique constraint on multiple columns in a database table?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a Laravel project and I have a scenario where I need to enforce a unique constraint on multiple columns in a database table. Specifically, I want to ensure that the combination of `column1` and `column2` is unique. How can I achieve this using Laravel Eloquent and migrations?

Here's an example of my migration file:

```php
Schema::create('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('column1');
    $table->string('column2');
    // ... other columns ...
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I want to prevent duplicate entries based on the values in both **column1** and **column2**. What's the best way to implement this in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your migration file, add a unique index for column1 and column2:

```
$table->unique(['column1', 'column2']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$table->unique(['column1','column2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

To enforce a unique constraint on multiple columns in a Laravel migration, you can use the `unique` method in the `Schema` facade. Here's how you can achieve this in your migration file:

```php
Schema::create('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('column1');
    $table->string('column2');
    // ... other columns ...
    $table->timestamps();

    // Add a unique constraint on column1 and column2
    $table->unique(['column1', 'column2']);
});
```

By using the `unique` method with an array of column names, you can enforce a unique constraint on the combination of `column1` and `column2`. When you run the migration, Laravel will create a unique index on these columns in the database, preventing duplicate entries based on the values in both `column1` and `column2`.

After adding the unique constraint, if you attempt to insert a record with the same combination of `column1` and `column2` as an existing record, Laravel will throw an integrity constraint violation error, preventing the duplicate entry from being added to the table.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/10871073

Answer (score 0):

`$table->string('email')->unique();`

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.